# how to convert time saved as int in mysql

Tags: mysql, time, integer

I have a column time in a table which is saved as an int in a 24hours format.
Example : 1900 (meaning 7:00pm) or 1000(10:00 am) or 930 (9:30 am)
What's the simplest way for me to convert it to time to be able to compare it with now()?

Comment: Of course you have tried something, right. So can you show us what you have so far please

Comment: I was thinking of going backwards maybe, meaning doing something like  
select substr(replace(time(now()),':',''),1,4); 
which would now(0 to the same format than my column type and then compare those numeric numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(`time`*100 AS TIME) FROM table
```

or

```sql
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(`time`*100, '%h:%i %p') FROM table
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f2f08682a6f8cf8410390b8998f7a800

Comment: that seems to do the job, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

a query like the below will help you convert the int you got into time :

`SELECT CAST(INSERT(CAST(LPAD(1200,4,0) AS CHAR(50)), 3, 0, ':') as TIME);`

Comment: Try that with `930` :)